# Second tab not showing in form boostrap

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

This my code
I have a form with bootstrap and 2 tabs, when I display the form shows the first tab, but when I click on the second tab nothing happens.
I dont know what I missing.......................................
...............................................................

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:70px">
 <div class ="card bg-light col-8">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs pull-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#contactos">Contactos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#domicilio">Domicilio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."?opc=".$opc."&id=".$id;?>" method="post" id ="formulario" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contactos">  
   <div class="form-row" > <!--linea1-->
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text1">ID</label> 
        <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campo1?>" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> <!--linea1-->
  </div> <!--tab contacto-->

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="domicilio">
   <div class="form-row" > <!--linea5-->
    <div class="col">  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text11">Calle</label> 
        <input id="text11" name="text11" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campo11?>" required <?php if ($opc == 'C'){echo "readonly";}?>>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_text11;?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--linea5-->
 </div> <!--tab domicilio-->
   <div class="form-row"> <!--linea9-->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a href="contactos.php" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</a>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> <!--linea9-->
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for bootstrap 5 as per [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior) you need to add `data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#{tabID}" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="{tabID}" aria-selected="true"` to the a tag with class `nav-link`

so your code should be

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:70px">
 <div class ="card bg-light col-8">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs pull-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#contactos" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contactos" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contactos" aria-selected="true">Contactos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#domicilio" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#domicilio" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="domicilio" aria-selected="true">Domicilio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."?opc=".$opc."&id=".$id;?>" method="post" id ="formulario" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contactos">  
   <div class="form-row" > <!--linea1-->
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text1">ID</label> 
        <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campo1?>" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> <!--linea1-->
  </div> <!--tab contacto-->

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="domicilio">
   <div class="form-row" > <!--linea5-->
    <div class="col">  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text11">Calle</label> 
        <input id="text11" name="text11" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campo11?>" required <?php if ($opc == 'C'){echo "readonly";}?>>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_text11;?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--linea5-->
 </div> <!--tab domicilio-->
   <div class="form-row"> <!--linea9-->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a href="contactos.php" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</a>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> <!--linea9-->
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

working example [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/basselhossam/Lzdm6tuw/)

Edit:

if you are using [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) just remove `-bs` from the data attributes so it would be `data-toggle="tab" data-target="#{tabID}" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="{tabID}" aria-selected="true"`

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:70px">
 <div class ="card bg-light col-8">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs pull-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#contactos" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#contactos" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contactos" aria-selected="true">Contactos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#domicilio" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#domicilio" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="domicilio" aria-selected="true">Domicilio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])."?opc=".$opc."&id=".$id;?>" method="post" id ="formulario" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contactos">  
   <div class="form-row" > <!--linea1-->
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text1">ID</label> 
        <input id="text1" name="text1" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campo1?>" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> <!--linea1-->
  </div> <!--tab contacto-->

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="domicilio">
   <div class="form-row" > <!--linea5-->
    <div class="col">  
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text11">Calle</label> 
        <input id="text11" name="text11" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $campo11?>" required <?php if ($opc == 'C'){echo "readonly";}?>>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_text11;?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--linea5-->
 </div> <!--tab domicilio-->
   <div class="form-row"> <!--linea9-->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <a href="contactos.php" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</a>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div> <!--linea9-->
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

working [fiddle for bootstrap 4](https://jsfiddle.net/basselhossam/wu6zgr7a/2/)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but second tab still not showing. I cant copy all code, because is very long, but there is something that is not working, like the example.

Comment: @FedericoCoco sorry I just noticed the bootstrap 4 tag you added I assumed you were using the latest version of bootstrap anyways I edited the answer and added section for bootstrap 4